# How to get one date for orders in a week and get it to appear in the MM-DD-YYY format not the ISO format using mongoldb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm working on a dashboard using mongodb, and I'm trying to display the date of the Monday that corresponds to the week in which an order was made. I would like the date to appear as MM-DD-YYYY, not in the ISO date format.

```
const weeklyOrders = await Order.aggregate([
      {

        $group: {
          _id:{ $dateFromParts: {
            weekYear: {$year: '$createdAt' },
            week: { $isoWeek: '$createdAt' },
            dayOfWeek: 1
          },
        },
         
            orders: { $sum: 1 },
          },
        },
        { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
      ]);
```

Gives me the date in the ISO format. Below, I had tried to get the date to display in the MM-DD-YYYY format, but now a date isn't showing up. I would really appreciate any help or guidance on how I can get the date to display in the format that I want.

```
 const weeklyOrders = await Order.aggregate([
          {
            $group: {
              _id:{ 
                day: {
                  $dateFromParts: {
                    isoWeekYear: {$year: '$createdAt' },
                    isoWeek: { $isoWeek: '$createdAt' },
                    isoDayOfWeek: 1
                },
              },

               
              },
                orders: { $sum: 1 },
              },
            },
            { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
            {
              $project: {
                day: '$_id.day',
                orders: '$orders',
              },
            },

          {
            $addFields:{
            
              day: {
                $let: {
                  vars: {
                      dateInString: {
                        $dateToString: {format: '%m-%d-%Y', date: '$createdAt' },}
                  },
                  in: {
                      $arrayElemAt: ['$dateInString', '$day']
                  },
                 },
               },
              
            },
          },
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use below aggregation then yoou can get the date in the format you need.

Note I just modified your aggregation filter too get date in desired format.

```
[{$group: {
  _id: {
    day: {
      $dateFromParts: {
        isoWeekYear: {
          $year: '$createdAt'
        },
        isoWeek: {
          $isoWeek: '$createdAt'
        },
        isoDayOfWeek: 1
      }
    }
  },
  orders: {
    $sum: 1
  }
}}, {$sort: {
  _id: 1
}}, {$project: {
  day: {
          $dateToString: {
            format: '%m-%d-%Y',
            date: '$_id.day'  
          }},
  orders: '$orders'
}}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes sense

Comment: Is there a way to get the weeks in-between the weeks I have data/orders to be listed?

Comment: what is  weeks in-between the weeks? can you share sample data and explain the problem here?